# CQWP Error when modifying webpart and ItemStyle.xsl : from example SP2010

Tags: web-part, xslt, content-query-web-part, item-styles

I am trying to create a webpart that would take blog posts from subsites under site and roll them up. I found a blog that describes exactly what I am trying to achieve [here.](http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2010/03/sharepoint-2010-content-query-for-blog.html) After following these steps:

1. Add CQWP to page and set content type values
2. Export the webpart and modify CommonViewFields to add fields

   ```
   <property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">Title, Text;PublishedDate, DateTime;Body, RichHTML;Author, Text;NumComments, Lookup;PostCategory, Lookup;</property>
   ```
3. Save, upload and select the webpart again
4. Modify ItemStyle.xsl from style library to include namespace:

   ```
   xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"
   ```

   and new template:

   ```
   <xsl:template name="BlogPost" match="Row[@Style='BlogPost']" mode="itemstyle"> 
       <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl"> 
           <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink"> 
               <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/> 
           </xsl:call-template> 
       </xsl:variable> 
       <xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle"> 
           <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle"> 
               <xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title"/> 
               <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/> 
           </xsl:call-template> 
       </xsl:variable> 
       <div class="custom_posttitle"> 
           <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate"/> 
           <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" title="{@LinkToolTip}"> 
             <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams = 'True'"> 
               <xsl:attribute name="onclick"> 
                 <xsl:value-of select="@OnClickForWebRendering"/> 
               </xsl:attribute> 
             </xsl:if> 
             <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams != 'True' and @OpenInNewWindow = 'True'"> 
               <xsl:attribute name="onclick"> 
                 <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$OnClickTargetAttribute"/> 
               </xsl:attribute> 
             </xsl:if> 
             <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayTitle"/> 
           </a> 
       </div> 
   <xsl:variable name="StartDate"> 
       <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@PublishedDate), 1033, 'g')" /> 
   </xsl:variable> 
   <div class="custom_date"> 
           <xsl:value-of select="$StartDate" /> 
   </div> 
   <div class="custom_description"> 
           <xsl:value-of select="@Body" disable-output-escaping="yes" /> 
   </div> 
   <div> 
       <table class="custom_postdetails" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
           <tr> 
               <td class="custom_author"> 
                       By: <xsl:value-of select="@Author" /> | 
               </td> 
               <td class="custom_comments"> 
                       Comments: <xsl:value-of select="@NumComments" /> | 
               </td> 
               <td class="custom_category"> 
                       Category: <xsl:value-of select="@PostCategory" /> 
               </td> 
           </tr> 
       </table> 
   </div>
   ```
5. Finally return to page and edit webpart; when i try I get an error, can't edit webpart. Now it seems I cannot edit content query webparts through browser at all without getting this error.

This is on my dev system so I am running under system account which is owner of everything. The ItemStyle is checked in and published, and there isn't an option for approval (which i am pretty sure means that as owner when I publish, there is no approval).

Yeah I know that I am asking for things like this when I grab some sample from online and post, but I am trying to learn this approach and I am simply wondering if someone might know why this is happening because of something I missed?

Always appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so just in case anyone is where i am at and experiencing the same trouble, i was able to resolve this by changing Body from RichHTML to Note in the .webpart file. I had a syntax error in the ItemStyle as well, but the above was correct.

Comment: While you've exported the .webpart file, you might as well make a copy of ItemStyle.xsl and point it to that - that way if you break it, you only break your web part and not every instance on the website.

Comment: cool. thanks, didn't even know I could do that.